# Creating a parallax effect for a non full width image in a container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

I have [this section of my site](http://danceforovariancancer.com.au/#acts) dedicated to acts which are going to be at the event. One of the acts' given picture is ridiculously vertical but the supplied info is little to none. So I thought I could make the picture extend vertically outside the constraints of the section and give it a parallax scroll effect.

Here is the whole section code:

```
<section id="acts">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 kujopad">
                <p>The Kujo Kings
                Known for their Ska/Punk anthems and high energy packed out shows, this 20 something band has built a strong Australian-wide following since forming in 2010.  The six-piece band are dedicated to entertaining fans with their catchy and humorous tunes, with dangerous amounts of energy, dancing, costumes and gratuitous fun being a consistent feature of their shows, the Kujo Kings are an act not to be missed!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 kujoimgpos" data-scroll-speed="6">
            <img style="height: 700px; width: auto;" src="img/Kujo%20Kings%20image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I tried to accomplish the effect by giving the div which holds the image a negative margin, which worked for hiding part of the top and bottom of the image above and below the section, and then applying a scroll speed to the div, which didn't work, and then the image, which also didn't work. I know of all the parallax.js and equivalents out there but in all the demos they do this for fullscreen backgrounds and I can't get it to work for my use case.

I can already see the flaws in my logic for the effect as giving a div a different scrolling speed would change the scroll speed right from the start and so would make it either disappear or be positioned totally wrong once the user scrolls to that section. Hopefully you guys can help :) I don't mind using js

I also gave the image a z-index of -10 just in case that might help with the parallax effect but as I said the logic there is flawed..

```
.kujoimgpos {
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

And I can't use position: fixed; because I only want the image to scroll slightly when it's scrolled past. Not completely which looks unrealistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should create a codepen or a jsfiddle with your code to make it easier for people to help you.

Here is my quick fix with jQuery. I did edit the html a little and added a couple of styles, please see the codepen for a working example.

Here is the jQuery that makes it work

```
//get heigth of the article part
var pContainerHeight = $('.kujopad').height();
console.log(pContainerHeight);
// assign same height to image part
$('.kujoimgpos').css({'height' : pContainerHeight + 'px'});

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) {
//pull bg image of kujoimgpos wScrill*1.6 pixels up
    $('.kujoimgpos').css({
          'background-position' : '0 -'+ wScroll *1.6 +'px'
    });
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/antonk52/pen/YwzqQN

this guy personally troubleshot and developed a solution for my site which you can see the result of [here](http://danceforovariancancer.com.au/#acts)

He changed a bit of the javascript to include an offset for when the scrolling starts and how the height is decided.

Here's the script and all classes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //get heigth of the article part
    var pContainerHeight = $('#heightid').outerHeight(true);
    console.log(pContainerHeight);
    // assign same height to image part
    $('.kujoimgpos').css({'height' : pContainerHeight + 'px'});

    $(window).scroll(function(){

      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      console.log($(this).scrollTop());
      if (wScroll => 1000) {
    //pull bg image of kujoimgpos wScroll*1.6 pixels up
        $('.kujoimgpos').css({
              'background-position' : '0 -'+ wScroll *0.2 +'px'
        });
      }
    });

});


.kujoimgpos {
    background-image: url('/img/kujokings.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.kujopad {
    padding-top: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

and the html section

```
<section id="acts" class="acts">
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 kujopad" id="heightid">
                <h1>The Kujo Kings</h1>
                <p>The Kujo Kings
                Known for their Ska/Punk anthems and high energy packed out shows, this 20 something band has built a strong Australian-wide following since forming in 2010.  The six-piece band are dedicated to entertaining fans with their catchy and humorous tunes, with dangerous amounts of energy, dancing, costumes and gratuitous fun being a consistent feature of their shows, the Kujo Kings are an act not to be missed!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 kujoimgpos">
        <! the image is here >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I was going to wait to reply till I had implemented it but I've gotten stuck with a problem. Thanks for using all my class names btw. I just copy pasted and changed the image url. I will change the script so it gets the height from a parent div instead of the padding div, but if you go http://danceforovariancancer.com.au you can see what happened when I tried to implement it, it's 1px height haha. I'm guessing it's something to do with the .kujopad class because all it doess is add a padding-top: 100px; Thank-you so much for the reply, I was attempting this solution: http://bit.ly/1jCD07G

Comment: Yuo should get the height of #acts and don't forget to remove a space in the html before the #acts as it adds an extra 20px on top of it. this way it should fully work for your purpose and you won't have to worry about the padding of left element

Comment: Are you taling about the two quatation marks which come up when you inspect element and is leaving that 20px white bit? Because I have been trying to get rid of that all day.... Suggestions?

Comment: I am, I have to take a look at the html, it could haave somethign to do to the comment you have before #acts, maybe try removing it. are you using any site generator?

Comment: nope it's been there all day and I added the comment after your answered actually to see where the empty space was placed. And no just the bootstrap framework and jquery, everything else is from scratch. It's in between the comment and the section... and no where else, I have set the global site font to raleway with .index {font-family} but deleting that doesn't help either

Comment: this looks like it's the problem but it's part of bootstrap and not happeneing anywhere else? https://i.gyazo.com/8bedc9c9c67e496b9ba2ab6b45452ce7.png 

Also I gave the section a class height and used that in your script but it still renders as 1px height?

Comment: the reason why it gives 1px height, is because you load you js in head section, so it is exectuted before the dom is loaded, either place your js before the closing body tag or wrap the js code I provided in `$(document).ready(function(){...my code...});` which will execute it only after the dom is loaded.

Comment: I opened [this chat thing if you are free to chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96960/discussion-between-lopu-and-antk)

Comment: Idk how people like you find the time to answer questions but thanks. I implemented it and there's a problem because it's not the first div of the page or even visible when you open the page. Is there anyway I could wrap all the previous divs and navs in a <section> and then a </section> right before the acts div and calculate the height of that to offset the beginning of the parallax effect? Also any reason why the picture is going further offscreen to the right than 100% width?